# Удалить ведущие нули одним sql запросом

Tags: mariadb

существует таблица, в которой > 100000 записей. В ней есть колонка с цифрами у которых есть ведущие нули. Например: 0005, 0050, 0500. Надо одним запросом у всех убрать ведущие нули. В итоге должно получиться: 5, 50, 500. Как это сделать?

Comment: какая версия mysql?

Comment: Mariab 10.1.39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под рукой нет именно этой версии, удалось проверить только на 10.3.

Можно использовать UPDATE:

```
update test
set id=SUBSTRING(id,REGEXP_INSTR(id,'[1-9]'))
```

Второй вариант - изменить тип на INT, если все значения подходят под маску '000[1-9]%'

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN id INT;
```

Вот тут [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=709faa35112e3cc121c31a1e76b83eab)

Comment: спасибо, первый вариант помог

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = columnname + 0
-- WHERE LEFT(TRIM(columnname), 1) = '0'
;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я, если честно, не вижу, что бы в этом ответе могло требовать хоть какого-то пояснения...